# Is it possible to have nested intervals (open or closed) such that$\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}I_n$ contains exactly two elements?

Tags: real-analysis

It's not a homework problem but I saw it in an Analysis book. How would I go about constructing this infinite set of nested intervals? If the intersection contains only two elements, my thinking is that the $nth$ interval has to contain just an infimum and supremum, where $inf(I_n) \leq sup(I_n)$. If anyone has any ideas I'd like to see.

Thanks!!

Comment: It is not possible. The intersection of nested intervals is again an (possibly null) interval. It either has 0, 1 or and infinite number of points.

Comment: Are you saying that this is possible but you don't know how? Because it sounds pretty impossible to me...

Comment: Hint: Let our two numbers be $a$ and $b$. Each of the intervals contains $(a+b)/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that it is true, i.e. $\bigcap I_{i}=\{x,y\}$ with $x\neq y$, then we have that the interval $(x,y)$ is nonempty. Take $z\in (x,y)$. Then for any $I_{i}$ we have $x,y\in I_{i}$, so $z\in (x,y)\subset I_{i}$ as $I_{i}$ is an interval. Hence $z\in I_{i}$ for all $i$, so $z\in\bigcap I_{i}=\{x,y\}$, i.e. $z=x$ or $z=y$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $x<y$ are such that $x\in\bigcap I_i$ and $y\in\bigcap I_i$, then for each $i$ we have $x\in I_i$ and $y\in I_i$ and therefore $[x,y]\subset I_i$ since $I_i$ is an interval. Hence $[x,y]\subset\bigcap I_i$. This proves that if two distinct points are in $\bigcap I_i$, then $\bigcap I_i$ contains every point between those two as well. As a corollary, if $\bigcap I_i$ contains at least two points, then it contains an infinite number of points.